# FFMPEG SlideShow - Only display first frame

Tags: android, ffmpeg, slideshow

I m using below ffmpeg command to generate video(slideshow) from list of images,but the issue is that its only displaying first image.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 3 -i image1.jpg -i image2.jpg -i image3.jpg -filter_complex [v][v1][v2] concat=n=3:v=1,format=yuv422p[a] -map [a] out.mp4
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after lot of practices got the solution and better ffmpeg command then above command.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i img-list.txt -f concat -safe 0 -i audio-list.txt -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 -r 24 -shortest -y -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" video.mp4
```

in above command input.txt will contains path of image files seperated with new line.

**input.txt**

```
file '*/image1.jpg'
file '*/image2.jpg'
file '*/image3.jpg'
```